# Bash: Running sed operation with file input

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I am trying to use sed in a bash script with a file as input. 
When I run the same command in command line, it works. But when I use the file as an input to a script with the sed command, I get

```
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
```

On command line:

```
sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/ input.txt
```

When I make this into a script with more than one sed command and pass the file as input, it doesn't work.

In the script I tried (none of them worked)

```
sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' < "$1"

sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' < '$1'

sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' $1
```

Script

```
./sed_script.sh input.txt
```

Comment: All your examples are missing a single quote in the `sed` command, is that a typo?

Comment: Did you create the script in a Windows text editor? I suspect it has CRLF line endings. Also note that you can't use `sed -i` when input is redirected from stdin (`<`)

Comment: I’m curious why you are so eager to use ``<`` in your commands in the script when you didn’t use it in the interactive command that works.

Comment: Fixed single quote typos. Thanks Jesse_b

Comment: @steeldriver, no, everything done in linux.

Comment: Try to `set -o xtrace    # show expanded command before execution` at the start of your script.  That way you can see what is happening.  Maybe `$1` is expanding to something you didn't expect...

Comment: I have tried to replicate the problem however like @steeldriver has mentioned `sed -i` will not work redirection from stdin. If you add `-x` at the end of your shebang, it will run your script in debug mode. Alternatively try defining `$1` in a variable and passing the variable to sed (still doesn't work with `-i` though)

Comment: Are you running this on some file that has spaces in its name?

Comment: Maybe the file doesn't exist where your script runs the `sed(1)` command. Without some further details, perhaps a stripped down script that fais the same way, it is very little we can do except wild guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your error, a file with a zero length name has to be used:

```sh
$ sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' ""
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
```

Since you say that this command is part of a script, this leads me to believe that either

1. the script is buggy and contains a typo in the variable name that is used when calling `sed`, as in

   ```
   filename=$1
   sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' "$fliname"    # should have been "$filename"
   ```

   or

   ```
   for i in something; do
       sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' "$1"      # should have been "$i"
   done
   ```
2. you may be using the script wrongly, e.g. by not giving it the correct options or filename arguments.

---

As for your attempted fixes, none of them are correct.  Since you are using `sed -i`, you *can't* read from standard input with a redirection from the file whose name is in `$1`.

The last variant,

```
sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' $1
```

is mostly correct, but the `$1` needs to be quoted as `"$1"`, or it will fail to correctly handle filenames with spaces or globbing patterns in their names etc.

It's is highly unfortunate that you never say what happens when you try these variants of the command in the script, and that you never say what the faulty command in the script actually looks like (or what the rest of the script actually does). This would have made debugging the issue easier.

Note that the command just above here (with the correction of adding double quotes around `$1`) is not guaranteed to work as we have no way of telling what is expected to be in `$1` at the time of calling `sed` in the script.

Comment: Thanks, This worked:   sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' "$1"

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are trying to replace pattern `abd` with `xyz` from your text file. I have tried the following on NetBSD and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' $1
```

The following was the outcome:

```
$ cat input.txt 
one.abd.
two.abd.
abd
three
four
$ ./test.sh input.txt 
xyz
xyz
xyz
three
four
```

I would remove `-i` and `<` from your script and it should work fine. Alternatively I have tried with success

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
sed 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' $input
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `/` before the final `'`? Even if it works without it I'd be worried. And why wouldn't `-i` work with the file name in a variable? Bash will substitute the filename before running sed... so sed should have no way of knowing how the filename was passed to it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That was a typo on my part on the post, rather than the script. I tested the script with `$1` in a variable and using the variable with `sed -i`. It did substitute the filename, however did not actually run `sed` on the command. Without `-i` both versions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

please try with this command which should work
command : `sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' $1` (make sure your pattern is correct)
if you use i then it will replace automatically  inside file.

Run -  `sed -i 's/.*abd.*/xyz/' input.txt`

Comment: This seems to be identical to something that the user already did.